# DropboxPaper API "paper/docs/create" doesn't work

Tags: dropbox-api, swiftydropbox

I'm trying to create new DropboxPaper document in my account [email address redacted], 
I'm use official Api and try to create file by "https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/paper/docs/create", the returned result is:

`{
    "error_summary": "insufficient_permissions/.",
    "error": {
        ".tag": "insufficient_permissions"
    }
}`

Somebody know what's is wrong? Please help me)

Answer (score 0):

[Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-Support-Feedback/Paper-API-Create-Paper-Document/m-p/375961/highlight/true#M21093 ]

It sounds like you're probably using a new Dropbox account, so the Dropbox Paper functionality is only available in the Dropbox filesystem, and not via the legacy Paper API endpoints. You can find more information here:

https://www.dropbox.com/lp/developers/reference/paper-migration-guide